# Why does Ruby on Rails not render some text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in a partial view file `_status.html.erb`.

```
<%=
    if session[:user].nil?
        "welcome new user"
         link_to( 'Sign in', login_path) 
    else
         render ( :text => "user name:")
         h(session[:user].name)
     end
 %>
```

The only thing that I see though is the value of `session[:user].name`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need to call render, unless it's located in another partial.

In erb:

```
<% if session[:user].nil? -%>
  welcome new user
  <%= link_to( 'Sign in', login_path) %>
<% else -%>
  user name
  <%= h(session[:user].name) %>
<% end -%>
```

Or in Haml:

```
- if session[:user].nil?
  welcome new user
  = link_to( 'Sign in', login_path)
- else
  user name
  = h(session[:user].name)
```

Comment: that's great, thanks. I didn't notice the -%> part until now. Thanks!

Comment: It's the <%= versus <% that is important. The -%> simply suppresses the blank line that would otherwise be sent to the output.